# Create simple graph object in Julia using Graphs.jl

Tags: graph-theory, julia

I am starting to study graph theory (I plan to use it in machine learning and/or bayesian inference). I want to code in Julia, and found the package [Graphs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/packages/packagelist/#graphs-graphs-build). But how can I use this package to create simple graphs? For example, this one:

[image]

It would be very useful if I undertood how to create an Julia object that represents this graph using `Graphs`. Its documentation lacks examples so I can't get started.

Comment: http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but as I said, the documentation lacks simple examples. Therefore, I'm kinda lost on how to create a simple graph with this package.

Comment: See if the [test programs](https://github.com/JuliaLang/Graphs.jl/tree/master/test) help get you started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Julia's [`Graphs` package](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/packages/packagelist/#graphs-graphs-build) has [`simple_graph`](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/graphs.html#simple_graph) interface for creating such small graphs. To manually create the above mentioned graph the following code is sufficient.

```
using Graphs

g = simple_graph(4, is_directed=true) # simple_graph(number_of_vertices, is_directed=true|false)
add_edge!(g, 1, 2)
add_edge!(g, 1, 4)
add_edge!(g, 2, 4)
add_edge!(g, 3, 1)
add_edge!(g, 3, 2)
add_edge!(g, 4, 3)
```

Short example for using an algorithm from the manual.

```
test_cyclic_by_dfs(g)
```

And here's a basic plot.

```
julia> plot(g)
```

[image: graphviz plot]

Comment: In general I would use LightGraphs.jl nowadays.