# Changing vertices' value with Graphs.jl

Tags: graph-theory, julia

I'm trying to make a Graph (to simulate a 2D [Ising Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_Model)) using the module Graphs.jl.

I've discovered how to construct a Simple Graph with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23977361/3667015) question but, using the answer provided, I can't find a way to change the vertices value. Maybe I should try another graph type but I really couldn't understand the documentation to find the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This package looks pretty good, but simple graphs have integers as vertices so you can't label them.  Therefore, you have to use the more general types ***ExVertex*** and ***ExEdge*** [see here](http://graphsjl-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/vertex_edge.html).  Using this interface correctly requires that the right types are constructed, which is hard using the REPL.  Here is a module you can use to aid in graph construction.

```
module GraphUtil
   import Graphs
   export empty_graph,add_label!,add_connection!

   function empty_graph()
      va::Array{Graphs.ExVertex,1} = {}
      ea::Array{Graphs.ExEdge{Graphs.ExVertex},1} = {}
      G = Graphs.graph(va,ea)
   end

   function add_label!(G,s::String)
      v = Graphs.ExVertex(Graphs.num_vertices(G) + 1,s)
      Graphs.add_vertex!(G,v)
      v
   end

   function add_connection!(G,from::Int,to::Int)
      va = Graphs.vertices(G)
      e = Graphs.ExEdge(Graphs.num_edges(G) + 1,va[from],va[to])
      Graphs.add_edge!(G,e)
      e
   end
end
```

Once you have access to a general graph, the vertex labels can be easily set

```
julia> using Graphs
julia> using GraphUtil
julia> G = empty_graph()
Directed Graph (0 vertices, 0 edges)
```

Add new vertices labeled "a" and "b" to ***G***; they will have index 1 and 2

```
julia> add_label!(G,"a")
vertex [1] "a"
julia> add_label!(G,"b")
vertex [2] "b"
```

connect vertex 1 and vertex 2

```
julia> add_connection!(G,1,2)
edge [1]: vertex [1] "a" -- vertex [2] "b"
```

Get the list of vertices

```
julia> va = vertices(G)
2-element Array{ExVertex,1}:
 vertex [1] "a"
 vertex [2] "b"
```

Change the label and/or attributes of vertex 1

```
julia> va[1].label = "c"
"c"

julia> vertices(G)
2-element Array{ExVertex,1}:
 vertex [1] "c"
 vertex [2] "b"

julia> va[1].attributes["weight"] = 2
2

julia> vertices(G)[1].attributes
Dict{UTF8String,Any} with 1 entry:
  "weight" => 2
```

Comment: I forgot I made this question xD I found the answer on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ohadle/11323991) and used it as a guide to implement my module already (the main point is to use `g = graph(new_vs, new_es, is_directed=g_dict["directed"])` to create the graph). But thank you very much for your answer! Your module is quite nice.

Comment: @kaslusimoes Sure thing, I feel that base Julia will get to where it needs to, but at least half of the effort is to enable use of all of the contributions.  Lack of docs can be frustrating.  My objective is to make sure nothing goes unanswered.  Interested how it works out for you.

Comment: As a had a direct motivatoin, my implementation isn't as general as yours (and I changed to matrices quite quickly because of the laziness of creating these graphs). Anyway, you can check it on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kaslusimoes/3c38ea40d7145dad7e03) or, the "final" version, on [this repo](https://github.com/kaslusimoes/MyIsing.jl)